# Develop e commerce web site in nopCommerce in mvc4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

i want to develop e commerce websites and i want to use technology is MVC4. some one suggest me about nopCommerce please guide me about this framework is it good for e commerce websites or any other framework you suggest. if this is good framework then please also guide me how to customize it any good video tutorial or ebook which you suggest.
 thank you

Comment: Nopcommerce is using MVC 5 since last update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nopCommerce is the popular open-source eCommerce solution. It provides fully customizable, stable & highly usable shopping cart. And it is totally free.

You can also download it's **source code** from [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx).

You can see the **demo** from [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/demo.aspx).

There is an **ebook available** for beginners [here](http://www.packtpub.com/getting-started-with-nopcommerce/book).

Lots of video tutorials are available on the internet, just google it. And almost all major web hosting providers also supports it.

**Finally conclusion:** It is good & perhaps the best free eCommerce solution available in the market. Go for it.